# Finding exposure time of a satellite camera

Tags: satellites, camera, luminosity

Note: I am not sure if this is the correct stack for this question

I'm working on a cubesat project, specifically on the camera payload. I've been tasked to find the exposure time of a VIIRS satellite used for the creation of this website https://www.lightpollutionmap.info

From what I've gathered from [here](http://www.dfisica.ubi.pt/~hgil/Fotometria/HandBook/ch07.html) and [here](https://books.google.hr/books?id=QMVgB-6NFxQC&pg=PR3&hl=hr&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) the output voltage of a sensor is:

$U_{out}=\frac{R}{K_mV(\lambda)}\cdot E_e\cdot t_e$

where $R$ is responsivity in $\frac{V}{lux-sec}$, $K_m$ and $V(\lambda)$ are luminous efficacy and efficiency, $E_e$ is irradiance of the source and $t_e$ is exposure time of the sensor.

Rearranging the above expression I got

$t_e=\frac{U_{out}K_mV(\lambda)}{RL_0\Omega}$ where $L_0$ is average radiance and $\Omega$ is the solid angle

I know this isn't correct because time shouldn't be inversely proportional to radiance. I have not found anywhere how to find exposure time given the above paramaters.

How do I find the exposure time of the camera?

Thank you

Comment: The map you linked to gives its brightnesses in magnitudes per square arcsecond, which are independent of basically everything about the hardware except for the spectrum over which the image is taken. There's no way you'll get exposure time from that map without knowing the calibration data they've used to produce it.

Comment: It gives average radiance which we can take to be at $\lambda$ = 550 nm for an estimate as the sensors are calibrated at that wavelength. There is a connection with the amount of light reaching the sensor and it reacting to it, otherwise the responsivity wouldn't be in those units.